# Can't use a dependent crate in Rust documentation tests

Tags: rust, rust-crates, rustdoc

I'm trying to write docs for a project I'm writing in Rust. One of the docs requires using `regex::Regex`. Here's the doc I'm trying to write:

````
/// Return a list of the offsets of the tokens in `s`, as a sequence of `(start, end)`
/// tuples, by splitting the string at each successive match of `regex`.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// use rusty_nltk::tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize;
/// use regex::Regex;
///
/// let s = "Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please buy me
///         two of them.\n\nThanks.";
/// let regex = regex::Regex::new(r"\s").unwrap();
/// let spans = regexp_span_tokenize(s, regex).unwrap();
/// ```
````

It gives me this error:

```
---- tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize_0 stdout ----
    <anon>:4:9: 4:14 error: unresolved import `regex::Regex`. Maybe a missing `extern crate regex`? [E0432]
<anon>:4     use regex::Regex;
                 ^~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

But when I add `extern crate regex;`, I get this error:

```
---- tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize_0 stdout ----
    <anon>:3:9: 3:19 error: unresolved import `rusty_nltk::tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize`. Maybe a missing `extern crate rusty_nltk`? [E0432]
<anon>:3     use rusty_nltk::tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:4:9: 4:14 error: unresolved import `regex::Regex`. Did you mean `self::regex`? [E0432]
<anon>:4     use regex::Regex;
                 ^~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Some relevant parts of relevant files are:

## src/lib.rs:

```
extern crate regex;
pub mod tokenize;
```

## src/tokenize/mod.rs:

```
extern crate regex;
pub mod util;
```

## (Top of) src/tokenize/util.rs:

```
extern crate regex; 
use regex::Regex;
```

What am I doing wrong with the layout of my project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [*The Rust Programming Language*, first edition](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/documentation.html) chapter on [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/documentation.html#documentation-as-tests):

> Here's the full algorithm rustdoc uses to preprocess examples:
>
> 1. Any leading `#![foo]` attributes are left intact as crate attributes.
> 2. Some common allow attributes are inserted, including `unused_variables`, `unused_assignments`, `unused_mut`, `unused_attributes`, and `dead_code`. Small examples often trigger these lints.
> 3. If the example does not contain `extern crate`, then `extern crate <mycrate>;` is inserted.
> 4. Finally, if the example does not contain `fn main`, the remainder of the text is wrapped in `fn main() { your_code }`

Point #3 is relevant here. When you have **no** `extern crate` lines, your crate is automatically added. Once you add the first `extern crate`, *no crates* will be automatically added — that includes your crate!

You will need to add `extern crate` lines for both `regex` and `rusty_nltk`.

Comment: I was just about to post this as an answer. I will give this the answer and add my solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

After being pointed to the docs, I solved it by wrapping a `main` around my code with `extern crate`s:

````
/// Return a list of the offsets of the tokens in `s`, as a sequence of `(start, end)`
/// tuples, by splitting the string at each successive match of `regex`.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// To return a list of spans based on whitespaces:
///
/// ```
/// extern crate regex;
/// extern crate rusty_nltk;
/// use rusty_nltk::tokenize::util::regexp_span_tokenize;
/// use regex::Regex;
///
/// fn main() {
///   let s = "Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please buy me
///           two of them.\n\nThanks.";
///   let regex = Regex::new(r"\s").unwrap();
///   let spans = regexp_span_tokenize(s, &regex);
/// }
/// ```
````

I decided to change my doc style to include `main`s for all examples, but if this isn't your style, you can add `#` before code to hide it from docs.